# How to make routes tickable inside a layer on a map with folium

Tags: python, dictionary, folium

I'm creating a program with Python that finds the best routes for workers. It display a map with their itinerary and time of itinerary. I have 3 layers, one for each transport car, metro and bike. When I tick or unticked them it display or erase them from the map. I would like to have the same features but with the duration of the run. Like if there was layers inside each one of the first 3 layers.

```py
layerVoiture = folium.FeatureGroup(name=description, overlay=False, control=True)
```

Some code describing the layer :

```py
layerVoiture.add_to(myMap)
mapTile = folium.TileLayer(tiles='OpenStreetMap') #StamenToner
mapTile.add_to(layerVoiture)
```

it displays this I would like to make the left part, where the duration of runs are displayed, tickable or untickable

[image: Layout]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `FeatureGroupSubGroup` to create groups within your `FeatureGroup`.

For example:

```
from folium import plugins
group_0_15 = plugins.FeatureGroupSubGroup(layerVoiture, name="De 0 à 15 minutes", show=False, overlay=False)
```

I am working on something similar and still have one issue: I can't combine radio buttons (set with `overlay=False`) and check boxes (set with `overlay=True`) in the legend (`LayerControl`). They are in two seperate areas in the legend. [Here is an example.](https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2019/29/5/1563546604-legend.png)

So if you only want to use radio buttons or check boxes, it should work. In my case, I am using only check boxes even though it is not exactly what I was looking for. [Here](https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2019/29/5/1563546706-legend2.png) is what I achieved, by creating 3 sub-groups in each group.

I hope it still helped!

Comment: Thank you ! Totally what i was looking for